# Trouble Running A Python Script

Tags: python, compiler-errors

Here's my code:

```html
name = input("What's your name? ")
print("Nice to meet you " + name + "!")
```

But when i enter a name, for example "john", it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "name.py", line 1, in <module>
    name = input("What's your name? ")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'john' is not defined
```

The version of python i'm using is "2.7.10".

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `raw_input` rather than `input`, as the latter attempts to evaluate what you enter while the former keeps it as a string.

Answer (score 2):

One of the problems with Python 2 is that it tries to take user input from the `input` function and execute it as Python code, instead of just returning it as a string. To avoid this problem, use `raw_input` instead:

```
name = raw_input("What's your name? ")
```

Comment: Thanks, First Time I Hear Of `raw_input()`!